# Using relative paths for tmp and log

Tags: joomla-3.4, global-configuration, logs

This should be a simple one but my installation is in a state where I cannot be sure what I am doing wrong. I wanted to be able to use relative paths for my tmp and log folders. They used to be full paths but I want to try an keep my installation portable to save some hair pulling later. Pertinent lines in my configuration.php

```
public $log_path = 'jrt/';
public $tmp_path = 'tmp/';
```

Am I able to use relative paths? Haven't found a compelling source

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, Joomla has the `$log_path` and `tmp_path` [set to absolute values by default.](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/server-settings/change-path-to-temp-folder)

The only problem which can occur with relative values is, that the corresponding folders might not be "recognized" and thus you have a permission problem.

You can easily test that, without harm to your installation:
Just change the `tmp_path` to a relative value and look up the permissions under:

System->System Information->Folder Permissions

If the value for `tmp_path` is set to "unwritable", you should probably change it back.

As for an official statement, I haven't found anything, either. Maybe I will update this post later with something I found.